# Create a dataframe from multiple pages stacked in one single text file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a text file of data that I want to read into a pandas dataframe. The file looks like this:

```
PAGE 1 ----- DATE --- NAME
TEST 001
MATERIAL A
Angle | Body 1 | Body 2 | Body 3
30    | 123    | 456    | 789
60    | 123    | 456    | 789
90    | 123    | 456    | 789

PAGE 2 ----- DATE --- NAME
TEST 001
MATERIAL A
Angle | Body 4 | Body 5 
30    | 123    | 456
60    | 123    | 456
90    | 123    | 456

PAGE 3 ----- DATE --- NAME
TEST 001
MATERIAL B
Angle | Body 1 | Body 2 | Body 3
30    | 123    | 456    | 789
60    | 123    | 456    | 789
90    | 123    | 456    | 789
```

There are one or more TESTs and one or more MATERIALs per file. Different TESTs will have different numbers of Angles or Bodies. I want to have all the data for a single TEST and MATERIAL in one dataframe like this:

```
TEST 001 MATERIAL A
Angle | Body 1 | Body 2 | Body 3 | Body 4 | Body 5
30    | 123    | 456    | 789    | 123    | 456
60    | 123    | 456    | 789    | 123    | 456
90    | 123    | 456    | 789    | 123    | 456
```

My initial approach has been:

```
 1. Parse the file to find every TEST and MATERIAL.
 2. Create a separate dataframe for each page containing TEST 001 and MATERIAL A
 3. Merge those dataframes on Angle 
 4. Continue iterating through each TEST-MATERIAL combo in the file.
```

This more or less works, but it's extremely kludgy and confusing, and is going to be slow if I use it on files containing very many tests. Is there a better way to tell Pandas to collate the data so that I can avoid making multiple dataframes when I only want one? I do not have the option to change how the data is structured in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a proposition using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) with the help of a *custom function* :

```
def get_tm(test: str, material: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = (pd.read_csv("textfile.txt", header=None, names=["DATA"])
                .loc[lambda x: ~x["DATA"].str.contains("PAGE", na=False)])
​
    m = df["DATA"].str.startswith("TEST")
​
    df["TM_NAME"] = df["DATA"].str.cat(df["DATA"].shift(-1), sep="/").where(m).ffill()
    df["ANG_BODY"] = "ANG_BODY/" + m.shift(2, fill_value=0).cumsum().astype(str)
    
    out = (
            df.loc[~m^m.shift(fill_value=True)]
                .pipe(lambda df_: df_.join(df_.pop("DATA").str.split("\s*\|\s*", expand=True)))
                .loc[lambda df_: df_.pop("TM_NAME") == f"{test}/{material}"]
                .assign(idx= lambda df_: df_.groupby("ANG_BODY").cumcount()+1)
                .pivot(index="idx", columns="ANG_BODY")
                .droplevel(1, axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
                .pipe(lambda df_: df_.set_axis(df_.iloc[0].str.strip(), axis=1))
                .dropna(axis=1).iloc[1:, 1:].rename_axis(None, axis=1)
                .sort_index(axis=1)
          )
​
    return out
​
```

Output :

```
print(get_tm("TEST 001", "MATERIAL A"))
​
  Angle Body 1 Body 2 Body 3 Body 4 Body 5
1    30    123    456    789    123    456
2    60    123    456    789    123    456
3    90    123    456    789    123    456

print(get_tm("TEST 001", "MATERIAL B"))

  Body 1 Body 2 Body 3
1    123    456    789
2    123    456    789
3    123    456    789
```

Comment: Thanks! That's much more efficient (and easier to understand) than my approach.